# Can I get user info for same user with linkedin API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Can I get user info for same user with linkedin API if user dont auth in my linkedin-api-application?

Answer (score 1):

All LinkedIn API requests require authentication to be made.  Once authenticated, you can retrieve profile information for the currently authenticated user by making a call to the People API:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json
```

More details are available here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin